# PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/801 error in imagick

Tags: php, laravel

when using imagick to count the page number of pdf file it shows the error. PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified.' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/801 error is showing.Iam using Xampp server and i installed ghost script to resolve this error my apache stops working.

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->pingImage($path);
echo $image->getNumberImages();
```

Comment: Do you solve your issue? I am getting this same issue.